# Thread was being aborted Error on Asynchronous job on ASP.NET MVC Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous

I am working on ASP.NET MVC Application.
I have a Job that runs after kicking submit button from UI.

To refresh the status for the Jobs that are running (Whether Submitted, Inprogress, Completed), I have implemented AutoRefresh functionality usign AngularJS feature that refreshes every minute. So long as I am on this Page, I am not getting any Thread Abort Error.
Sometimes these jobs takes 4 to 6 Hours to complete. When I move out of this Page, it throws that error.

I increased httpruntime executionTimeout to a large number. Still that is not helping.

When we run this from local,it doesn't throw this error. When we run this from Dev Environment, then it throws this error.

How to get rid of this error "Thread was being aborted"?

Thanks,
Ritha

Comment: At a guess, Id say you need to look at the logic/design of your application -  I would suggest seeing if you can decouple the status update job from the page in some manner (having not worked with Angular I can't say whether or not that is possible or how to do it).

Comment: The solution is don't run long running jobs inside of the IIS server, use a service on the server to run the job. Another option is use a 3rd party libary like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) that can run long running jobs and will try to keep the server alive (But for a job that takes 4-6 hours to complete you might need to run Hangfire in service mode to get it to reliably finish instead of running it from inside IIS)